# My CSS code error on html (not match properly)

Tags: php, html, css, web, layout

i have some problem in my little webpage training project. I wrote this question page because my problem is little specific and i cant find solution that works on my webpage training project.

My website screenshot 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF0aF.png

the HTML

```
<?php
if(!defined("INDEX")) die("--");
$artikel=mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM `Tabel Artikel` order by id_artikel desc");
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($artikel)){
    $isi = substr($data['isi'],0,800);
    $isi = substr($data['isi'],0,strrpos($isi,""));
?>
    <div class="artikel">
        <h2 class="judul"><?=$data['judul'];?></h2>
        <p>
            <?php if ($data['gambar']!="") ?>
            <img src="../gambar/artikel/<?=$data['gambar'];?>" class="gambar-artikel" width="200">
                <?=$isi;?> ...
            <a href="?tampil=artikel_detail&id=<?=$data['id_artikel'];?>">Selengkapnya</a>
        </p>
</div>
<?php }
?>
```

The CSS part

```
.box{
    padding:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.artikel{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.gambar-artikel{
    float:left;
    padding:3px;
    margin-right:5px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

As you can see on my website picture, the content wont float properly on left and the '$isi' wont appear even there are a data on sql data base in that table. I hope there are some solution so each content would float left properly and the $isi would appear. I appreciate any suggestion. Cheers!

Comment: all rendered HTML?

Comment: all on php file sir

Comment: what is the result of your php, it is HTML, post that code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i assume...you want to get all your articles (artikel) to left side...add `clear: both;` to your `.artikel` class

```
.artikel{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

and put your `$isi` into `<span></span>` or something...text is now "under" the image

Comment: thankyou sir, its already fixed my layout placement but the $isi part still wont come out. If its not a bother, can you explain it why use `clear: both;` can fix it?

Comment: for `$isi` look for code inspection in browser, its "under" the image

more about `clear`  css https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Comment: actually, the text its not appearing at all, the layout is fine. I suspect the problem is on `$isi = substr($data['isi'],0,800);
    $isi = substr($data['isi'],0,strrpos($isi,""));` . i need that code so not all the part of text are appearing (its for article text preview)

Comment: thanks to mr jDolba. I alrd fix missing content by deleting `$isi = substr($data['isi'],0,strrpos($isi,""));` . I got a glimps of idea how to fix it because your post. Thanks for your suggestion, have a nice day :)